# What's a good open-source debugger & memory analyzer for Windows?

Tags: windows, open-source, debugging, memoryanalyzer

In a Unix world I've been happily using **gdb** for debugging and **valgrind** for memory analyzation.

Are there open-source quality alternatives for Windows?

I'm looking for lightweight pieces of software that do what you need, and never get in your way (just like gdb and valgrind).

Comment: GDB is actually available for windows as well.

Comment: You really can't beat MS visual studio.  Accept the fact that it is not open source and get the free version.  You are at a disadvantage without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio Express edition is free (but not open source).

In the Microsoft Debugging Tools there's also the WINDBG debugger.  Also free, not open source.